# Android bluetooth connect to paired device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

currently I have a device (a bluetooth module for an Arduino) that I would like to connect to via bluetooth. But every time I try to connect, nothing happens. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? 
My Code:

```
private static final UUID CONNUUID = UUID.fromString("0000110E-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");


public void connectDevice(BluetoothDevice bd){
       try{
           pairDia = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Connecting...", true, true);
           BluetoothSocket bs = bd.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNUUID);

       }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           this.finish();
       }
    }
}
```

Ultimately I would like to connect to the device, then create a socket to it which I can then read and write bytes to. Thanks

Comment: what does the log showed in the `Logcat` and any error in the `stackTrace`?

Comment: There is no stack trace, just nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to call `connect()` on your `BluetoothSocket`:

```
// ...
BluetoothSocket bs = bd.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(CONNUUID);
bs.connect(); // note: blocking call
// ...
```

See [example code on Google Developer pages](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient).

Answer (score 0):

If your device is paired. Then get the device `UUID` first with this:

```
final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// now tm.getdeviceID()...and is this equal to your CONNUUID?
```

Set the bluetooth permission... in manifest.. and now see the list of devices by the following:

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();   

Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = adapter.getBondedDevices();    

for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {

   String sDeviceName = device.getName().trim();

   Log.d("device_found", sDeviceName);
}
```